# How to find out if method was called in a bool value in Rhino mocks?

Tags: c#, nunit, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to write a parameterized unit test using NUnit and Rhino Mocks that can return true or false depending on whether a certain mocked method was called. `AssertWasCalled` is not right because it makes the test fail right away. I only want a `bool` value.

```
[Test]
[TestCase(1,2, Result=false)]
[TestCase(1,1, Result=true)]
public bool SomeTest(int a, int b)
{
    ...
    someObject.CheckValues(a, b); // logs something if values are different.

    return mockLogger.WasCalled(x => x.Log(null));
}
```

`WasCalled` ofc does't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stub the Log method on mockLogger to set a bool when it's called, and return that:

```
bool logMethodWasCalled = false;
mockLogger
    .Stub(x => x.Log(Arg<string>.Is.Equal(null))
    .Do(new Action<string>(_ => logMethodWasCalled = true));

// Run test...

return logMethodWasCalled;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use expectation:

```
mockLogger.Expect(x => x.Log(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));

mockLogger.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

If you want to check if parameter is null use:

```
mockLogger.Expect(x => x.Log(Arg<string>.Is.Null));
```

Another way is to use:

```
triggerManagerMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Log(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
```

It that case you can use Stub method to model behavior and AssertWasCalled to check the call.